# Nmap match three ports

Tags: lua, network-programming, nmap

I'm trying to make a script for nmap, which only executes its action, if three ports are open.

The end result would be if port 515, 631 and 9100 are open for tcp traffic, script should print a message (at first, later it should make a os detection).

My script so far:

```
function portrule(host,port)
    return port.state == 'open' and 
    port.protocol == 'tcp' and 
    515 <= port.number and 
    631 <= port.number and
    9100 <= port.number

end

action = function(host, port)
    return "hello"
end
```

But this will execute for all ports after 9100 is hit.

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `==` instead of `<=`?

Comment: Nope, that'll never match.

Comment: I meant:  `(515 == port.number or 
    631 == port.number or
    9100 == port.number)`

Comment: That will match once for each port, i only want/need it to match once all ports are open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSE scripts match based on [a rule function](https://nmap.org/book/nse-script-format.html#nse-format-rules), and there are four different types. You are using a `portrule`, which tests **each** port on a host. Since you want to test **multiple** ports on a host, you should be using a `hostrule` instead.

The `hostrule` is tested after the state of all ports is known. You can check the state of all of these ports by using the [`nmap.get_ports`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/nmap.html#get_ports) function like [`nfs-ls`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/nfs-ls.html) does, or you can check individual ports using the [`nmap.get_port_state`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/nmap.html#get_port_state) function like the [`nbstat`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/nbstat.html) script does. Actually, `nbstat` looks like a good example of exactly what you want to do.